# When you override __eq__ in a class, do you also need to override __hash__?

Tags: python-3.x, hash, overriding, equality

I'm making a node class in Python 3 which I will be storing in a min-ordered multi-tree structure. I overrode the `__eq__` method which tests for equality by comparing two unique integer instance variables.

1. Will this approach work for finding nodes in the structure by comparing equality?
2. Do I also need to override `__hash__`?

Answer (score 3):

*Yes, you have to override `__hash__`*.

The general rule is: if two instances are equal (wrt to `__eq__`, i.e. `a==b` is True), then they must have the same hash.  Otherwise, all sorts of things can misbehave.

Also, it sounds to me `__eq__` is not enough for minimum.  At the very least, you'd need to define `__lt__`.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm making a node class in Python 3 which I will be storing in a min-ordered multi-tree structure

If it's the only use, and they are only used internally so user code isn't ever supposed to see a `Node`, and your code doesn't store them in dicts or sets, or call any functions which do, maybe you can get away without overriding `__hash__`.

But those are very strong restrictions, which can't really be enforced. And there's no benefit to *not* overriding `__hash__` to be consistent with `__eq__`. So you still should do it.